# PCRE binary files?

Tags: c, pcre, binaryfiles

I would like to parse binary files with PCRE. My tactic until now was to use `fgets` to read a line of a file, then parse that line using `pcre_exec`.

This will not work for me now because the "lines" end with a null byte rather than a newline. I did not see a way to have `fgets` stop at a null byte rather than newline.

### Edit

The functionality would be similar to running `grep -az PATTERN FILE`

Comment: That's correct, frets doesn't work well with binary files. can you give more detail about the bin file? you want to parse using some structs for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, no luck, you need to read your binary file **byte by byte** and check for `'\0'`.
You can then store this bytes on a buffer and:

- Doing some comparaison on the fly with your PATTERN

or

- If you want to keep data for later processing, you can store this buffers on a linked list for example (if you don't have a huge files).

Hope this help.

Regards.